# Context free grammar over { a^n * b^(n+3) | n >= 0 }

Tags: context-free-grammar

Context free grammar over `{ a^n * b^(n+3) | n >= 0 }`

So far I have this, but I don't think it's entirely correct

`S --> aSbS | TbTbTb`

`T --> aTbT | lambda`

Is the `aSbS` even necessary?

**SOLUTION**

`S --> aSb | Tbbb`

`T --> aTb | lambda`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have isn’t close, I’m afraid. You need to make sure that each time the grammar generates an $a$ on the left, it also generates a $b$ on the right. If the language were $\{a^nb^n:n\ge 0\}$, we could do it with $S\to aSb\mid\lambda$: applying the first production $n$ times for $n\ge 0$ would produce $a^nSb^n$, and then applying the second would produce $a^nb^n$. Can you see how to make just a small modification to this grammar to make it generate your language instead?

Comment: Ah I knew I was making a simple mistake. Can you check the solution now?

Comment: @heyzuse: What you have now will work. You can simplify it even further: $S\to aSb\mid bbb$.

Comment: @heyzuse: You’re welcome!